# oscillation of newton iteration for arctan

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

We consider the function f(x) = arctan(x), we know that the newton iteration might diverge for some starting value too far from the zero. But it might also lead to an oscillation between two values as you can see in the following graph :

[image]

the goal of the problem is to find an expression for the function g. I've tried a lot of algebra but didn't manage to find any answer.

Comment: What is g(x) supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration in Newton's method for $\arctan x$ is

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - (1+x_n^2) \arctan x_n.
$$

The red dots in your graph, plus the zero of $\arctan x$ at $x=0$, are the points $x_0$ for which $x_2 = x_0$; they cause the sequence $(x_n)$ to oscillate back and forth between two values. Because $\arctan x$ is odd, it is also true for these points $x_0$ that $x_1 = -x_0$.

Plugging this into the iteration we find that the red dots (plus the zero at $x=0$) satisfy

$$
-x_0 = x_0 - (1+x_0^2) \arctan x_0,
$$

or, rearranging,

$$
2x_0 - (1+x_0^2) \arctan x_0 = 0.
$$

In other words, the red dots, plus the zero of $\arctan x$ at $x=0$, are the zeros of the function

$$
g(x) = 2x - (1+x^2) \arctan x,
$$

which is the red curve in your plot.

Comment: I'm missing applying the newton algorithm twice in order to find a point, which after two iterations comes back to itself.

Comment: @FrankPuck We aren't applying the algorithm twice, per se. The idea is to write down the recurrence relation, write down what it means to oscillate between two values (this is what $x_2 = x_0$ means), deduce from the oddness of arctan that this is equivalent to $x_1 = -x_0$, then plug that into the recurrence relation for $n = 0$.